# Selecting and clicking a link within a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, grid

I'm tinkering around with some javascript and was wondering how I would go about selecting the first class within a class. What I would like is to be able to go to a page and have a userscript automatically go to the first available instance's link in the grid of items. The sample html looks along the lines of this:

```
<div class="item-wall">
    <div class="grid-item" data-column-index="0" data-pdpurl="http://www.LINK1.com"> … </div>
    <div class="grid-item" data-column-index="1" data-pdpurl="http://www.LINK2.com"> … </div>
    <div class="grid-item" data-column-index="2" data-pdpurl="http://www.LINK3.com"> … </div>
    <div class="grid-item" data-column-index="3" data-pdpurl="http://www.LINK4.com"> … </div>
    <div class="paging-bar hidden"> … </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
```

More specifically, the desired end result would be to just go to the first link, `www.LINK1.com`. I've tried to work with the indexing but I have no clue how to go about this.

So far, this is what I have producing results.

```
waitForKeyElements ("DIV.item-wall", pickGrid)

function pickGrid (jNode) {
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);    
}
```

Unfortunately, this goes through the whole item wall and selects the last instance and goes to that link.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Under what event should this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) to get what you need. Something like `document.querySelectorAll(".item-wall>.grid-item:first-child")` should work.

Expanded Answer

Going off of what you state in your question, if you just want to go to the URL specified by the data- attribute you can do this: `window.location.href=document.querySelectorAll(".item-wall>.grid-item:first-child").getAttribute("data-pdpurl")`

Comment: Yes! From the documentation, this looks like this is what I need. I'm still confused as to implement it though. How exactly would I be able to use this and go to the url? Thanks for the information

Comment: See my edit. If you have to perform the navigation with the click event, you should be able to combine what you have already with my answer to get what you need.

Comment: Thank you! I used window.open() with a _self parameter which did the trick. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Using Tony's selector, plus a bit more, you can easily get the link:

Pure JS:

`document.querySelector('.item-wall>.grid-item:first-child[data-pdpurl]').getAttribute('data-pdpurl')`

jQuery:

`$('.item-wall>.grid-item:first-child[data-pdpurl]').attr('data-pdpurl')`

http://jsfiddle.net/paulinfrancis/yxsHN/

Comment: Very thorough with the fiddle. Thank you!